# Showing all rows of one column, regardless if related table doesn't have all items

Tags: sql-server

I've got three tables

```
dbo.Products (productname, price)
dbo.Stock (productid, storeid, stocklevel)
dbo.Store (storename)
```

Basically the Stock table is a relational table between both Products and Stock. It will show all products that have a stock for that particular store. This i am able to do, and this is what I get:

Store Name: BeachFrontStore

```
Products  StockLevel
Pencil    400 units
Bic Pen   640 units
```

Now I want to also add products that have no stock for that current Store. This way the user has a visual feedback.
What i need to accomplish:

Store Name: BeachFrontStore

```
Products  StockLevel
Pencil    400 units
Bic Pen   640 units
Eraser    'no units'
```

The eraser would be a product that has no relation inside dbo.Stock, but does exists in dbo.Products.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use `LEFT JOIN`s on your tables to return values with nulls:

```
select p.productname, sl.stocklevel, s.storename
from products p
left join stocklevel sl
    on p.ProductID = sl.ProductID
left join store s
    on s.storeid = sl.storeid
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a696e/1)

Comment: Acutally, i already had that and it does work, but for some very wierd reason it shows less products than it should! I have 1100 products in the dboProducts. But doing this only shows 39!

Comment: @user1603568 can you post some sample data for each table?

Answer (score 0):

You basically need an `OUTER JOIN` between products and stock to get all products - whether they have 
stock or not.

Something like:

```
SELECT
     p.ProdudctName,
     ISNULL(s.StockLevel, 'no units')
FROM
   dbo.Products p
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.Stock s ON p.ProductID = s.ProductID
WHERE
   (s.StoreId = 42 OR s.StoreID IS NULL)
```

This gives you the products and their stock - for a given store (here: StoreId = 42) - regardless of whether there's stock for that product - or not. Those products that are not stocked will return a `NULL` for their `StockLevel`, which I capture with the `ISNULL` function and convert it to `no units` for display.

Comment: thanks for your help. I had already tried an OUTERJOIN, but i noticed you added a IS NULL at the WHERE. I followed your tip and it lead me to show a few more products, but no the whole table. I have 1100 products and it shows only 39 (before the ISNULL it would only show 8). I'm starting to think it may be a configuration problem, because simple logic tells me this code should work!!